# Troubles with local letters PentahoPDFReporting

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pentaho

I am using Pentaho Report Designer 3.8.3 and I have small, aesthetic problem with fonts.

I have implemented, or better say, I am aimplementing OpenSans font into my pentaho.

Its cirrent state is, that i have installed this font into Linux(which is my pentaho runing on) and also into java. But i still have 2 problems with fonts:

1.) I see OpenSans font in html only when i open it on PC where it actually is installed. Whenever i open report with openSans font on machine where it is not installed, it change it for something else, Arial for example.
(I have added OpenSans to: '/usr/lib/jvm/' and also into: '/usr/share/fonts')

2.) After publishing report to PDF, I see only '?' instead of accentuated characters. But in html, I see no '?', each letter is as it should be.
(I have added
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.output.pageable.pdf.Encoding=ISO 639-1 #my language code, Slovak
into '/home/pentaho/pentaho/biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/classes/classic-engine.properties' file)

Does anyone have an idea wht else should I try to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you can do with html export other than doing the usual approach of setting the font-family so it has something to fall back to.

However in PDF look carefully at the pdf export options, you'll see there's a "embed fonts" option. Enable that and your pdf will work anywhere!

Comment: Well, I would like to set something like "force browser to use this font". Like you have "fontface" option in CSS.